# How to convert an -1 through 1 input to 0 through 1 in Lua

Tags: math

How do I convert an -1 through 1 input to 0 through 1. I have tried but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: value = (value + 1) / 2?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to map some interval `x1..x2` to `y1..y2`, you can apply the following logic:

1. Shift the interval such that the left side of it is at 0: `value-x1`
2. Expand/contract the interval: `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)` gives you the ratio by which to expand/contract, so you simply multiple by it: `(value-x1)*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`
3. Shift the interval to the new position, such that the left side is at `y1`: `(value-x1)*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)+y1`.

Substituting all the values from your example (x1..x2 is -1..1 and y1..y2 is 0..1), we get: `(value-(-1))*(1-0)/(1-(-1))+0`, which is the same as `(value+1)/2`.